# Continuous function integration

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function (defined for all $x$) and that the values of the following integrals are known:

$$\int_0^1 f(x)~dx = 5  $$
$$\int_{-1}^1 f(x)~dx = 3 $$
$$\int_0^2 f(x)~dx = 8  $$
$$\int_0^4 f(x)~dx = 11 $$

Evaluate these integrals:
A.) $\int_0^2 f(2x)~dx$
B.) $\int_0^\pi (\sin x)f(\cos x)~dx$
C.) $\int_2^3 xf(8-x^2)~dx$

Question: I am starting a calc 2 course, and need a refresher on procedures on integration problems. I'm okay with problem A but need help on approaching B and C.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you solve A? The rest actually works the same, it's just substitution.

Answer (score 1):

As menag said, you can use substitution for those. I'll do B), the third is yours.

If you take $y=\cos(x)$, then $dy=-\sin(x)dx$, so $$ \int_0^\pi\sin(x)f(\cos(x))dx=\int_0^{\pi}--\sin(x)f(y)\ dx=\int_1^{-1}-f(y)\ dy=\int_{-1}^{1}f(y)\ dy=3. $$

Comment: Uldreth, I'm sorry but I don't understand how you used the known integral from -1 to 1